# Symfony displaying flash message after backing to the same page

Tags: symfony

Im adding flash message on form submit.
After successful submission im redirecting to route, then displaying the message via base twig template.

But when user goes to another location on the site and then clicks "back" button in the browser message is appearing again.

Is this normal behavior or im doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior since you're returning to a cached version of the previous page, unless it's over SSL or certain headers are set on the server.

Comment: Could you get more specific about that headers? im interested.

Comment: @KonradAlbrecht HTTP cache-control: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Answer (score 0):

What doest you "back" button like like ? Is it a proper link to go the previous page or something in javascript ? (In this case it would be a normal behaviour I assume)